# Closure of set in set notation involving a combination of metrics

Tags: metric-spaces

Let

$A=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb R^2 :|x|\leq2\}$

$B=\{(x, y)\in\mathbb R^2 :0 <x+y <2\}$

$C$ is the intersection of $A$ and $B$

I have to write down the closure of $C$ in  set notation for the metric

$d ( (x, y), (w, z))=|x-w|+d_{0}(y, z)$

Not sure how to go about this. My limited knowledge of closure is turning inequalities to strict inequalities. I think I just need all points that I can put a ball around for all radius lengths that lie in $C$, but cant imagine what these points are or balls look like.

Thank for any help

Comment: What is $B$ again?

Comment: B is all the points between the lines y=-x and y=2-x